# Rails 6 pluralize(count, word) VS word.pluralize(count) - different results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using Portuguese in my Rails 6 app and want to use the pluralizer.

So I added the Portuguese rules to my inflections. (https://gist.github.com/mateusg/924574)

The word `casal` (couple) in plural is `casais`.

When I do

`pluralize('casal',2)` I get `2 casais` (correct)

But when I try

`'casal'.pluralize(2)` I get `casals` (wrong)

I am not worried about the number but about the fact that one way pluralizes correctly and the other not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your pluralize arguments backwards? https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize Is your locale set correctly?

Comment: My local in the app config file was set correctly. But apparently it has to be set within the method again.

Answer (score 7):

The default locale for `pluralize` as a helper is I18n.locale.

For the [String method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-pluralize) it is `:en`. You'll have to pass in `I18n.locale` or avoid the method.

Comment: Thanks! 'casal'.pluralize(2, :'pt-BR') resolved the issue.

Comment: @almo Be sure to use `'casal'.pluralize(2, I18n.locale)` to avoid hard coding the locale.

Comment: This was new for me too +1.